# Wrong incrementation of counter?

Tags: indexing

### Context

I would like to add automatically numbered highlighted comments in text.

### Attempt

Following this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503674/18190) I wrote the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand\showmycounter{\stepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter}

\definecolor{aquamarine}{rgb}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}
\newcommand{\my}[1]{\sethlcolor{aquamarine} 
   \protect\hl{Comment \showmycounter: #1} \sethlcolor{yellow}}

\begin{document}
some text 
\my{my first comment}\\
some more text
\my{my second comment}

\end{document}
```

which unfortunately for some strange reason increments the counter in steps of five.

[image]

### Question

> Could you please tell me how to get a unit increment on this counter?

PS: I am a bit of a newbie at latex programming. Let me apologise in advance if this question is dumb.

Comment: Don't put the `\stepcounter` inside the argument of `\hl`, so change the definition of `\my` to `\newcommand\my[1]{\stepcounter{mycounter}\sethlcolor{aquamarine}\protect\hl{Comment \themycounter: #1}\sethlcolor{yellow}}` Do you intend to use this in a moving argument (so `\caption`, `\section`, etc.)?

Comment: Which typo? :-)

Comment: Using `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand` defines `\my` to be `\protect\my␣` and `\my␣` is then what you want.

Comment: Because there are situations in which you don't want the macro to be protected, also `\DeclareRobustCommand` doesn't check whether the macro is defined or not and silently redefines it in case it is already defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing my comment as an answer: You shouldn't put `\stepcounter` inside of the argument of `\hl`. Instead increment the counter before it and only put `\themycounter` inside `\hl`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\definecolor{aquamarine}{rgb}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\my}[1]
  {%
    \sethlcolor{aquamarine}\stepcounter{mycounter}%
    \protect\hl{Comment \themycounter: #1} \sethlcolor{yellow}%
  }

\begin{document}
some text 
\my{my first comment}\\
some more text
\my{my second comment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The processing of `\hl` requires multiple passes over its argument in order to do measurements. You discovered that there are five passes and each one increments the counter. Note that `\stepcounter` acts globally.

You can avoid plunging into the innards of `soul` with some more work.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{aquamarine}{rgb}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}

\newif\ifstep
\newcommand{\stepcounteronce}[1]{%
  \ifstep
    \global\stepfalse
    \stepcounter{#1}%
  \fi
}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand\showmycounter{\stepcounteronce{mycounter}\themycounter}
\newcommand{\my}[1]{{% an additional group to do \sethlcolor locally
  \global\steptrue
  \sethlcolor{aquamarine}%
  \hl{Comment \showmycounter: #1}%
}}

\begin{document}

some text 
\my{my first comment}

some more text
\my{my second comment}

This is again \hl{yellow}

\end{document}
```

By adding `\global\steptrue` you start the machinery that allows `\stepcounteronce` to do `\stepcounter` only the first time.

Note the additional group, which allows to avoid explicitly redeclaring `\sethlcolor`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this alternative solution. And for the double group improvement.